# Compute the norm of matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be $n\times n$ matrix, consisting entirely of 1's.
Show, that $\|M\|_{op}=\sup_{x\in C^n}|Mx|=n$.

Comment: What sort of norm do you have on $\mathbb{C}^n$ Also you need to fix the expressions for the operator norm. The way it is written, the supremum ( maximum in this case) needs to be taken over all x of length one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $Mx = (e^T x) e$, where $e=(1,...,1)^T$. Hence $\|Mx\| = |e^Tx | \|e\| = \sqrt{n} |e^T x| \le n \|x\|$.

Setting $x={1 \over \sqrt{n}}e$ gives $Mx = \sqrt{n}e = n x$, hence $\|M\| = n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* your matrix is proportional to a one-dimensional projector, i.e.

$$ M = n |\chi\rangle \langle\chi|$$

with

$$ |\chi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{j=1}^n |j\rangle $$

Comment: Thank you. But we did not study projectors. Is it possible to use Chauchy-Schwarz inequality, or something like that.

Comment: Absolutely. In fact $|Mx| = n |\langle x|\chi\rangle|$. Now you can use Cauchy–Schwarz.

Comment: Can you direct me please to the prove of that fact you 've just mentioned. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the definition of 1-D projector. What is $|j>$ means? Thank you.

Comment: @Alexs It's just "bra-ket" notation (google it, you'll find tons of stuff). Think of $|j\rangle$ as the vector with a $1$ at position $j$ (and other entries zero). Likewise you can think of $|i\rangle\langle j|$ as the matrix with entry 1 at position $i,j$ (and other entries zero).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots ,x_n)^T$. Then

$Mx=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}1x_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n}1x_i,\dots ,\sum_{i=1}^{n}1x_i)^T$ and

$||M||=\sup_{||x||=1}{||Mx||}=\sup_{||x||=1}\{n|\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i|\}\leq \sup_{||x||=1}\{n\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|\}=n ||x||=n$,

if using $p$-norm with $p=1$ for $\mathbb{C}^n$ (inequality follows from the triangle inequality). Equality is achieved for $x=(1,0,\dots ,0)$ for example.

Comment: $\|M(1,0,...,0)^T\| = \sqrt{n}$, not $n$!

Comment: $M(1,0,\dots ,0)=(1,1,\dots ,1)$ and its $p=1$ norm is the sum of absolute values of the entries. So equal $n$. Are you using a different norm?

Comment: I assumed it was the Euclidean norm. In another comment, the OP mentioned the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality which would imply Euclidean...

Comment: I assumed the same initially, but realised that the problem was easier with $p=1$ norm. The reason was that I had difficulties in the case $p=2$ - so for example I was not convinced that I could get the last inequality (as you have) easily. @Alexs should have specified.

Comment: I see, the last inequality follows from Cauchy-Schwartz.